# c# framework 4.5 not include System.Web.Extensions

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2012

I try to add System.Web.Extensions in my vs2012 C# desktop application but it give me error. "The type or namespace name 'Extensions' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web' (are you missing an assembly reference?) " . I already add Ajax toolkit in reference. My application framework is 4.5 full not client reference. Please help me out for this error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

System.Web.Extensions is obsolete in 4.5.

Please see [this MSDN link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh419161(v=vs.110).aspx#extensions), it describes each member replacement.

Comment: Open the above site. Click on the System.Web.Extensions link. It described each member replacement.

Comment: Hello! Thanks for reply. I already study this link but I want System.Web.Extensions for JavaScriptSerializer. and there is no other option for this object. please guide me

Comment: Hello! I found option.System.Web.Script.Serialization is alternate use for JavaScriptSerializer. Thank you very much for your help... :)